# Inserting from MS SQL Server to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure that INSERTs data from the MSSQL DB tables to my MySQL DB tables and vice versa. What do I need to do this?

I have looked into two solutions.

1. Creating a linked server that will allow me to write and Query data from MySQL using stored procedures in MSSQL.
2. MySQL Migration Toolkits. How ever this option seems like an overkill, since I only want to make a few INSERTS and SELECTS between the two

So I lay my trust in you and hope someone has had similar problems in the past and would be so kind and give me the best way to do this. Especially would the 1st option work?

Who ever helps me will have my undying gratitude.

EDIT: 
Forgot to mention they reside in different servers (running debian and MS)

Comment: Have you considered dumping the MSSQL data into csv, then import it into Mysql?

Comment: What version of SQL Server and MySQL are you using?

Comment: Dumping data would not work, since I need to triggered or timed procedure that will run every 5 min. It would create unneeded steps in the process. For the version info:  SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 and 5.5.37-0+wheezy1 protocol v: 10

Comment: So this is not a one-time transfer?

Comment: No, it will be multiple times per hour. I need the 2 databases to be as identical as possible at all times 5-15 minute latency can be tolerated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to do this regulary

- **LinkedServer** and `OPENQUERY` could be good, if you are moving not too much records per cycle.
- **Integration Services Package** is a good solution if you want to move lots of data (like thousands or millions of rows).

You can schedule them with **SQL Server Agent**.

The `INSERT` is a bit tricky with `OPENQUERY`:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM MySQL_Table')
SELECT * FROM dbo.SQLServer_Table
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM MySQL_Table')
VALUES ('Value1', 'Value2', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. So I can query MySQL tables with MSSQL T-SQL syntaxes without worrying too much about the compability after linking them? My biggest worry is writing the queries and then having to find out that some of the basic commands like INSERT, LEFT JOIN, UPDATE would not be compatible, because of the syntax issues...

Comment: You have to use the MySQL syntax in the `OPENQUERY`, and this stands to source components in SSIS to. T-SQL syntax won't work, inside the `OPENQUERY`, but outside of it, you should use T-SQL. I've edited the answer to show how to insert into MySQL with `OPENQUERY`

Comment: @Pred how to dump mssql data from one server to mysql of another server

Comment: @insoftservice That is something you usually cannot do easily and automatically. [See the questions already asked in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=migrate+data+from+mssql+to+mysql). Also your question is extending the scope of the current one and should be asked separately. Please read [ask] in [help].